# Address specific parent using the Sass ampersand (&) selector

Tags: sass

I have the following simple scss:

```
.selector1,
.selector2 {
    /*Some properties*/

    &[disabled] {
        /*More properties*/
    }
}
```

What I would like to do, however, is to address the parents separately, is the best solution simply to declare the rules un-nested as below?

```
.selector1,
.selector2 {
    /*Some properties*/
}

.selector1[disabled] {
    /*Properties*/
}

.selector2[disabled] {
    /*Different properties*/
}
```

Is there a way to differentiate parent selectors when using the & selector so I can nest the rules similar to the first example?

Answer (score 2):

There's probably some way to do this using the [selector manipulation functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#selector_replace-instance_method), but there would be so much effort/code involved with this that it would simply be more efficient to not nest at all.

For your specific example, extends are an option:

```
%foo {
    /* stuff */
}

.one {
    @extend %foo;

    &[disabled] {
        /* different stuff */
    }
}

.two {
    @extend %foo;

    &[disabled] {
        /* other stuff */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you can use the `at-root` property to come up with a similar result. But as you realised it's cleaner to declare the rules un-nested.

```
.selector1,
.selector2 {
    /*Some properties*/

    &[disabled] {
     /*Some properties*/

     @at-root .selector1[disabled] {
       /*Different properties*/
     }
   }
}
```

The output will be:

```
.selector1,
.selector2 {
  /*Some properties*/
}

.selector1[disabled],
.selector2[disabled] {
  /*Some properties*/
}

.selector1[disabled] {
  /*Different properties*/
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/905436fde032bac27685